# How to communicate SSL handshake failure information between two different server configurations on nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, tls1.2

I have two `nginx` servers running locally, each serving a 1X1 pixel image, and its own certificate. This may be an unconventional requirement, but what I want is that if server 1 has an `SSL` `handshake` failure, then this information should travel to server 2, which upon hearing this information, sends a redirect. Is something like this possible? The only information I have about the first server which fails is through the error logs which register a `SSL` handshake failure, but I am not sure how to communicate this to server 2. And since I want to do a redirect for the same client, I am not sure if using error logs is the best idea.  Is there some way to for example, set a particular variable in server 1, and then read that in server 2. Upon reading this, server 2 sends a redirect to a chosen domain name.

Comment: You may start by explaining more your server1/server2 setup because it looks strange and hence you are maybe creating a problem yourself that has a simpler solution. Also since this is not programming related, you will be more on topic at [sf]. But to summarize if there is an handshake error, this came back to the client, which will not continue the exchange, whatever you do on the server. So I fail to see how you want to have server2 start to intervene there...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek its something of an unconventional use-case that I am testing locally. I do realize that the connection with the first server would be broken down once there is a handshake error, but the connection with server 2 would still be alive, right? So I was wondering if its possible to do a redirect by server 2, once I know that server 1 has had some sort of an error (on server-side). The fact that server 1 has had a failure can be traced via error logs right?

Comment: "but the connection with server 2 would still be alive" the connection from where? From the client? The client only connected to server 1 if I understood correctly. Please switch over to [sf] and give a proper schema about who connects to who, in order to make things clearer/

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Will do, thanks for pointing out!